# What's the difference between Distribution and iOS Distribution certificates?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've noticed that our Apple Developer Account contains two different types of certificate:

- iOS Distribution
- Distribution

The first is self-explanatory, but what purposes does the more generic sounding "Distribution" certificate serve?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Xcode 11, Apple abolished the distinction between certificates for different platforms and instituted unified certificates covering iOS, macOS, and so on. That is what the blanket Distribution certificate is. It replaces the iOS Distribution certificate.